# Get Response and Assert the same in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

Hi i'm calling a API which gets my data, i need to assert with the response in loadrunner. Can anyone help with this ?

```
Action()
{
    web_custom_request("entityGet", 
        "URL=http://localhost/t1/api/entityManageService/create", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=1", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://localhost:8085", 
        "Snapshot=t66.inf", 
        "BodyFilePath=CreateAPI.json",
        LAST);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See functions in the web_reg_...() name as well as web_get_int_property() for your options for data and status collection on the response.